# Not waiting for a method call to finish before calling another method

Tags: java, swing, frame

I need a bit of help.
I'm just after coming back to programming after being made unemployed.

I'm trying to learn Java and I have run into a difficulty.

The problem is that I want to call a method that should ask the user for an input by pressing a button. This will return the chouce back to the class that called the method.

```
    public class ButtonMain {
        private static CreateButton cButton;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            cButton = new CreateButton();
            cButton.launchButton();
            switch(cButton.getSelect()) {
                case 'a' : System.out.println("German Car");
                    break;
                case 'b' : System.out.println("Japanese Car");
                    break;
                default : System.out.println("Incorrect Car Selected");               
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The rest of the code is as follows

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CreateButton implements ActionListener {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private char select = ' ';

    public CreateButton() {
    }

    public void launchButton() {
        createFrame();
        createLabel();
        createButton1();
        createButton2();
    }

    private void createFrame() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Cars");
        mainFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        mainFrame.setLocation(300, 300);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setPreferredSize(null);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(3, 1));
    }

    private void createLabel() {
        label1 = new JLabel("Cars", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label1.setSize(200, 100);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(label1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void createButton1() {
        button1 = new JButton("Mercedes");
        button1.setSize(200, 50);
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(button1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void createButton2() {
        button2 = new JButton("Lexus");
        button2.setSize(200, 50);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(button2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button1) {
            select = 'a';
            System.out.println(select);
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == button2) {
            select = 'b';
            System.out.println(select);
        }
    }

    public char getSelect() {
        return select;
    }
}
```

What is happening is that the output should read a or b and then whether German or Japanese cars was selected but i'm getting the incorrect car selected.

Comment: Try and remember, Swing is an event driven environment.  That is something happens and you respond to it. It's a concept that can a little getting to use to ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you will not have the selection information at the moment when main is called. Better to handle this in the ActionListener itself.

*or*

Once a Swing component has been realized, all code that might affect or depend on the state of that component should be executed in the event-dispatching thread.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. Its that your code is running through and nothing is stopping it. The `cButton.launchButton()` simply shows the frame and the code after it runs. Since `select` is initialized to space char "Incorrect Car Selected" is printed when the program starts. Your actions on the buttons are working correctly. Your switch statement should be in the `actionPerformed` method.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == button1) {
        select = 'a';
        System.out.println(select);
    } else if (e.getSource() == button2) {
        select = 'b';
        System.out.println(select);
    }

    switch (getSelect()) {
    case 'a':
        System.out.println("German Car");
        break;
    case 'b':
        System.out.println("Japanese Car");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Incorrect Car Selected");
    }

}
```

Comment: Try putting a break point on the main at the `swtich` statement. Debug the code and wait for the frame to show. Then continue after the break point and I think you'll see what's happening.